# Radio button not working with loop

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form. In this, the user selects one of the values from the radio button. From all the questions i could select only one answer. but the loop should allow to select  one answer from each question.

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{url('quiz/check')}}"
{!! csrf_field() !!} 
@foreach ($quiz as $q)
    {{ $q->qid }}.  
    {{ $q->question }}<br>
    <input type='radio' name='mycheck[".$q->qid."]' value='1'>     
    {{ $q->opt1 }}<br>
    <input type='radio' name='mycheck[".$q->qid."]' value='2'>     
    {{ $q->opt2 }}<br>
    <input type='radio' name='mycheck[".$q->qid'."]' value='3'>    
    {{ $q->opt3 }}<br>
    <input type='radio' name='mycheck[".$q->qid'."]' value='4'>   
    {{ $q->opt4 }}<br><br>

@endforeach        
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Get result</button>
                            </form>
```

the form is redirected to this controller.

```
public function check(Request $request)
  {
    $count=0; 
    $input=$request->all();
        $ch = DB::select('select * from quiz where category="gk" ');
        return View('quiz.check',['quiz'=>$ch,'input'=>$input,'count'=>$count]);     

 }
```

And i have $count variable 0. which should increase by 1 with every correct answer.
view: `quiz.check`

```
@foreach ($quiz as $q)

   @if($input['mycheck'][$q->qid]==$q->answer)
    {
        $count=$count+1;
    }
@endif

@endforeach        

You scored {{$count}}.
```

Comment: You didn't push your $input array to the View. View('quiz.check',['quiz'=>$ch, 'input' => $input]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i should be doing.

```
<input type='radio' name='mycheck[{{$q->qid}}]' value='1'>
```

In controller:

```
public function check(Request $request)
  {
    $count=0; 
    $input=$request->all();
    $mycheck=$input['mycheck'];
        $ch = DB::select('select * from quiz where category="gk" ');
        return View('quiz.check',['quiz'=>$ch,'input'=>$input,'count'=>$count,'mycheck'=>$mycheck]);     

 }
```

And in the view:

```
@foreach ($quiz as $q)

   @if(array_key_exists($q->qid, $mycheck) && $mycheck[$q->qid]==$q->answer)
      {{$count=$count+1}}

@endif

@endforeach        

You scored {{$count}}.
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url('quiz/check')}}"
{!! csrf_field() !!} 
@foreach ($quiz as $q)
{{ $q->qid }}.  
{{ $q->question }}<br>
<input type='radio' name='mycheck_{{$q->qid}}' value='1'>     
{{ $q->opt1 }}<br>
<input type='radio' name='mycheck_{{$q->qid}}' value='2'>     
{{ $q->opt2 }}<br>
<input type='radio' name='mycheck_{{$q->qid}}' value='3'>    
{{ $q->opt3 }}<br>
<input type='radio' name='mycheck_{{$q->qid}}' value='4'>   
{{ $q->opt4 }}<br><br>

@endforeach        
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Get result</button>
                        </form>
```

Comment: yes, this allows to check for answer from each question, but after that mycheck variable is undefined in quiz.check view while comparing.@sunilwananje

Comment: `if($input['mycheck_{{q->qid}}']==$q->answer)` this is what i edited to.